# pandas dataframe add column based on lookup values

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I've used the best answer but it doesn't seem to work when trying to use more than 2 positional arguments. I want to add Disk as an option to the Dimension named 'CloudWatch'.

What I have:

```
data_1 = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

data_1['ADDED_COLUMN1'] = np.where(data_1.DIMENSION.isin(['S3', 'Glacier']), 
'VM', 'Other')
```

What I want:

```
data_1['ADDED_COLUMN1'] = np.where(data_1.DIMENSION.isin(['S3', 'Glacier', 
'CloudWatch']), 'VM', 'Other', 'Disk')
```

---

Original Question -

I have a CSV with 2 columns and I need to create a lookup table within pandas that will add a column according to the value of that row. Example:

```
DIMENSION    ACCOUNT NAME
Tax          Tiger 360
Config       Tiger 220
S3           Lion 200
Lambda       Tiger 550
Glacier      Lion 100
```

What I want to add:

```
DIMENSION    ACCOUNT NAME    ADDED_COLUMN1     ADDED_COLUMN2
Tax          Tiger 360        Other             Tiger_Group
Config       Tiger 220        Other             Tiger_Group
S3           Lion 200         VM                Lion_Group
Lambda       Tiger 550        Other             Tiger_Group
Glacier      Lion 100         VM                Lion_Group
```

How would I add those columns and base them off the DIMENSION value and the ACCOUNT NAME value for each one? (For reference, ADDED_COLUMN1 depends on the DIMENSION value and ADDED_COLUMN2 is dependent on the ACCOUNT NAME)

Also, the additional data isn't something I have on hand, it's something  I want to create/add. If it's easier to put it as a lookup table in a CSV or into the actual code.

So far I just have this:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

#turn the csv to a pandas dataframe
data_1 = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

Comment: It is not clear if the values that you are adding as additional columns come from other existing dataframes or are computed on the current dataframe.

Comment: it comes from a lookup table from another csv but I could also insert it into a dataframe

Comment: Provide a clear example of your problem - context, sample inputs, expected outputs.
Refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no general way. To avoid iterating over rows, you would want to use vectorized operations.
You could use `np.where` to test your relation or dependence on other columns while assigning values to a new column. For general operations, regular lambda functions can be used.

```
data_1['ADDED_COLUMN1'] = np.where(data_1.DIMENSION.isin(['S3', 'Glacier']), 'VM', 'Other')

data_1['ADDED_COLUMN2'] = data_1['ACCOUNT_NAME'].str.split(' ').apply(lambda x: x[0]+'_Group')
```

Comment: is this for a lamda function? I'm not using lambda for this, just regular python

Comment: Lambda functions are part of regular python. It is used in the second line of my answer.
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=lambda#lambda

Comment: what if i were to need another value in ADDED_COLUMN1 besides VM and Other? I tried and it said it only takes 2 positional arguments

Comment: Of course it takes two arguments as the documentation states.
The basic structure is - `np.where(condition, true_value, false_value)`. The `true_value` or `false_value` arguments could themselves be `np.where` clauses.
In this way `np.where` can be nested like and if-elif-else construct.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the additional data is available in pandas dataframes as well ... you can use the merge functionality of pandas ... refer https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html ... similar to JOINs in TSQL

In the simplest form it would be something like

```
new_df = pd.merge(left_df, right_df, how='inner', on='Dimension')
```